# Getting 400 response on uploading image to asp.net core api from xamarin forms UWP app

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi, xamarin.uwp

I have the following code in MainPage.cs

```
 private async void UploadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = "http://localhost:53416/api/upload";

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
                    "\"file\"",
                    $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

and this in my Asp.net core controller UploadController.cs

```
 [Route("api/Upload")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

On executing the call from a UWP app I am getting 400 Bad request and the method does not hit,
whereas on hitting the same url using postman including an image in the form data is working fine.
[image]

Target framework is .net core 3.1

One more thing is that on removing the parameter "[FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file" from the Post method so that it will be like

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
```

the method is getting called.

Am I doing something wrong
any idea anyone!

Answer (score 0):

check the size of the Image, Asp.Net core has a default 30MB request size limit you can increase the limit if needed: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/increase-file-upload-limit-for-aspdotnet

Comment: if possible consider adding the code snippet that makes this happen.